# Como enviar notificaciones a un usuario que se encuentra desconectado? Usando websockets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

Estoy iniciando con websockets y estoy implementando las notificaciones, pero no me queda claro como implementar esto, ya que cada vez que el usuario se conecta o refresca la pagina un nuevo id del websocket es creado, siendo ese el suyo, ahora, el usuario A le da like a un comentario del usuario B, ese usuario B esta desconectado, cuando entre tiene que ver o recibir la notificacion de que a alguien le gusto su comentario, pero como dije anteriormente, cuando el usuario B se conecta es que se crea el id, por lo que no puedo emitir un evento para notificarle hasta que se conecte

Comment: Solucion: NO PUEDES, si quieres enviar notificaciones a alguien que este desconectado no podras por medio de WebSockets, en su lugar deberas usar algo llamado push notifications, un ejemplo de push notifications es `onesignal`.

Comment: @Riven disculpa por contestar tan tarde, pero llevo tiempo usando oneSignal, no encuentro la manera o el lugar donde me expliquen de enviar notificaciones a un usuario, si ese usuario no esta online no recibir la notificacion hasta que se loggue

Comment: El funcionamiento por defecto de `OneSignal` es registrar a los usuarios al usar su servicio, lo unico que debes hacer es comunicarte con `OneSignal` y llamar a una funcion de `OneSignal` desde `React` de esta manera el dispositivo quedara subscrito a `OneSignal` cuando queda subscrito las notificaciones seran recibidas por el usuario asi el usuario tenga la `app/navegador` abierto o no, y asi este conecado o no, por lo tanto es un tema mas bien de configuracion.

Comment: Este video utiliza `ionic` en conjunto con `Angular` y `OneSignal` para poder que enviar notificaciones push al usuario, checalo y te dara una mejor idea acerca de lo que deberias hacer con `React` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j0Jz5ka5Co

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, si bien es verdad lo que comenta sobre el websocket quizá cambiando el enfoque pueda resolverlo. El websocket debe ser una parte de la estructura, poniéndolo en claro, podemos crear una clase u objeto "usuario" que en sus atributos puede tener id, nombre, edad y además puede tener un websocket. De esta manera las notificaciones pueden ser dirigidas al id de usuario indistintamente del socket id que se le proporcione cuando este se conecta. De esta manera lo podrías manejar sin preocuparte por lo demás.
Espero te sea útil.